# Display count 0 values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

TableA has the data as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
001     A       0
001     B       0
002     C       0
003     D       0
```

I want to see the count of records `group by` `Col1` and `Col2` where `Col3 = 1`
May be the query as follows:

```
Select Col1, Col3, Count(1)
From TableA
Group By Col1, Col2
Where Col3 = 1
```

Since there are no records with `Col3 = 1` no records will be displayed, but I still want to display the values with count as 0.
For example the output is as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    CountOfRecords
001     A       0
001     B       0
002     C       0
003     D       0
```

Could you please help me to get output as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use conditional aggregation:

```
Select Col1, Col2, Count(case when Col3 = 1 then 1 end) as CountOfRecords
From TableA
Group By Col1, Col2
```

Comment: @VenkateswarluAvula,  Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

firstly you write wrong sql statement, you can not use **Where** clause after **Group by** clause.. you need to use before group by.. if you want to use filter after group by use **Having** clause..
second if there is no matching column for 'Col3 = 1' then you did not get any result.. for that you need to use **case** statement or sub queries.
otherwise do not use group by clause rather than use simple sql statement.